# parsing the date object in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
Date.parseWeird=Date.prototype.parseWeird=function(d)
{
    return new Date(Date.parse(d));
};

var d = /Date(-65424600000)/
```

How can i parse this date and show in MM/DD/YY format.

```
16/09/1956
```

Comment: I'm not really understanding the question here.  Are you trying to parse the negative number as a `Date`?

Comment: What sort of a thing is `/Date(-65424600000)/`?

Comment: @John: Many of your questions have a negative score. It may be worth looking at some higher-scored questions to see how it's done!

Comment: @Tomalak Gerek'kal: Can't help if someone marks a negative score, no one really understands that if someone is not able to explain properly... they give negative stuffs... i am learning... i am editing the question back

Comment: That is the format from a JSON string from .NET. I'm assuming it is supposed to be a string. Also, the negative number is the time since UNIX Epoch but not going forward from 1970 but backwards from 1970

Comment: @John: You _can_ help it, as evidenced by the fact that better-formed questions do not have this problem. Providing precision information and describing your requirements concisely will lead to higher scores and more accurate answers.

Comment: @John: Your edit doesn't add any clarification or answer our queries. You just wrote out the same vague, unclear question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remove the extra:

```
Date.parseWeird=Date.prototype.parseWeird=function(d)
{
    return new Date(parseInt(/-?\d+/.exec(d)[0], 10));
};

var x = Date.parseWeird('/Date(-65424600000)/');
alert((x.getMonth()+1) + "/" + x.getDate() + "/" + x.getFullYear());
```

The express is looking for 0 or 1, `?`, negative sign, followed by any number, `+` ,  of digits, `\d`.

Comment: Thanks... for this code.. can u explain me the regular experssion a little bit and what does exec do

Comment: Don't forget `x.getMonth() + 1`

Comment: John I've explained the expression. @Alex, thank you for pointing that out. I always forget that.

Comment: I think my regex is easier to understand, no? `d = d.replace(/[^\-\d]/g,"");`

Comment: @mplungjan, perhaps it is. I am not a RegExp expert by any means. I usually just hack something together that works; then forget what all the symbols mean.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of fixing it on the client, fix it on the server

http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/02/20/good-date-times-with-json-net.aspx

> JsonConverters
>
> With no standard for dates in JSON, the number of possible different
>   formats when interoping with other systems is endless. Fortunately
>   Json.NET has a solution to deal with reading and writing custom dates:
>   JsonConverters. A JsonConverter is used to override how a type is
>   serialized.

```
public class LogEntry
{
  public string Details { get; set; }
  public DateTime LogDate { get; set; }
}
```

[Test]

```
public void WriteJsonDates()
{
  LogEntry entry = new LogEntry
  {
    LogDate = new DateTime(2009, 2, 15, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc),
    Details = "Application started."
  };

  string defaultJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entry);

  // {"Details":"Application started.","LogDate":"\/Date(1234656000000)\/"}

  string javascriptJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entry, new JavaScriptDateTimeConverter());

  // {"Details":"Application started.","LogDate":new Date(1234656000000)}

  string isoJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entry, new IsoDateTimeConverter());

  // {"Details":"Application started.","LogDate":"2009-02-15T00:00:00Z"}

}
```

If not, does this work for you?

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/kM2wP/)

```
Date.parseWeird=Date.prototype.parseWeird=function(d) {
  // remove anything not a digit or - and convert to number
  return new Date(parseInt(d.replace(/[^\-\d]/g,""),10));
};

var d = "\/Date(-65424600000)\/"
var newDate = Date.parseWeird(d);
var mm = newDate.getMonth()+1;
if (mm<10) mm="0"+mm;
var dd = newDate.getDate();
if (dd<10) dd="0"+dd;
document.write(""+mm+"/"+dd+"/"+newDate.getFullYear())
```